# LESS Compiler Converts RGBA() to Hex

Tags: css, less, rgba

I am creating a LESS stylesheet with the [SimpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless) compiler, and I notice when I create an entry using the CSS `rbga()` function, like this:

```
@contentDefaultOpacity: 0.5;

header#main-header {
    nav.navbar {
        div.container-fluid {
            div.collapse {
                ul.nav {
                    li {
                        a {
                            @alpha: 255 * @contentDefaultOpacity;

                            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, @alpha);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler throws away the `rgba()` and outputs this instead:

```
header#main-header nav.navbar div.container-fluid div.collapse ul.nav li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Is there a way I can retain the `rgba()`?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the `rgba()` in the output? Is that even valid CSS? Your LESS compiler seems to be correctly compiling its own syntax into equivalent CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LESS' `rgba()` function takes a percentage between `0%` and `100%`.
You're passing `128`, which is fully opaque.

Comment: *facepalm* Yep, I should drop that `255 *`. Silly me. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to generate the *[CSS rgba()](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color)* function (instead of static hex color codes generated by Less), you can do so by using a string with interpolated variables, and the `~` operator to remove the quotes. This Less code:

```
@contentDefaultOpacity: 0.5;

a {
    @alpha: @contentDefaultOpacity;
    color: ~'rgba(255, 255, 255, @{alpha})';
}
```

will generate the CSS:

```
a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```